# angularjs $http.delete breaks on ie8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

```
$http.delete('/api/carts/' + productCode).
  success(function() {
    cart.products = someMethod();

    updateTotals();
  }).
  error(function() {
    console.log('Could not remove product from card: ' + productCode);
  });
```

IE8 complains that "expected identifier" on the first line. The code works fine in Firefox, Chrome, etc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that `delete` is a javascript keyword and IE8 parses it slightly incorrectly. According to the standard, identifiers can be called `delete`. A quick fix is:

```
$http['delete']('/api/carts/' + productCode)
```

A little ugly, and I don't think the good angular people should have named that method delete, but that fixes your problem

Answer (score 3):

`$http.delete(path)` is a shortcut for `DELETE` requests.
So as the shortcut breaks on IE8, besides calling by their uglly form: `$http['delete']`, you can call using the original mode:

```
$http({method: 'DELETE', url: path})
```

Answer (score 2):

delete is the JavaScript reserved keyword, and IE parse it as a keyword.
Here is the solution.
http://tech.pro/tutorial/1238/angularjs-and-ie8-gotcha-http-delete

Here is the javascript reserved keyword list

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

so its better to use `$http['delete']` instead of `$http.delete`

Comment: I would include the solution as part of the answer instead of just the URL, since the link you posted could become dead in the future.

Comment: indeed, the link has become dead