# Web API Delete not working on IE 10

Tags: angularjs, azure, internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api

I am using Angular JS + CORS + Web API. I am able to make an HTTP request for GET, POST and PUT. However IE shows "DELETE" request always in pending state.

I tried to add traces on server side & it's responding correctly but somehow IE shows that request in pending state only.

> This code works for all browsers excepts IE 10.it works on local & not on production.I'm using Azure to deploy API.

"The requested resource does not support http method 'DELETE'." my web api code is:

**Config Code**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        EnableCorsAttribute CorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors();
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Controller Code**

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
[Authorize]
public IHttpActionResult Delete()
{
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.userName)) return BadRequest();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.clientId)) return BadRequest();

        var result =  _repo.DeleteRefreshToken(this.userName, this.clientId, this.session);
        return new CustomErrorResult(this.Request, System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Comment: How you call delete requests on Angular? Have you tried `$http['delete']` as the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479123/angularjs-http-delete-breaks-on-ie8

Comment: Request reaches to API & API is sending back the response, but IE keep showing it in pending state.